# Is it possible to start learning swift without previose programming expirience?

Tags: swift

I wa never coding myself before, but I'd like to give it a try and start from Swift. Do you its possible without previous coding expirience or do I need to star from something else?

Comment: [Getting Started with Swift Development](https://mayvenstudios.com/blog/getting-started-swift-development-4-first-steps-take)

Comment: Swift is a good way to start with a modern language. But you not only need to learn Swift, you have to learn Xcode and the API to access all the functions needed in an app. So, start studying "Intro to App development with Swift" and "App development with Swift" to learn the basics. Once done, you can search for Stanford course for iOS development, to learn about app architecture.

Answer (score 1):

*"Swift can open doors to the world of coding. In fact, it was designed to be anyone’s first programming language, whether you’re still in school or exploring new career paths. For educators, Apple created a free curriculum to teach Swift both in and out of the classroom. First-time coders can download Swift Playgrounds—an app for iPad that makes getting started with Swift code interactive and fun."*
**Quoted from** https://developer.apple.com/swift/